# Put Ellipse on the edge of a line in the same view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Either it is super simple and I just didn't find the solution yet or I'll start to go insane soon.

I just want to draw a `Line` in an `ItemsControl` on a `Canvas` and that `Line` should have an `Ellipse` on both edges. Like this:

[image]

My ItemsControl looks like this:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type systemEnvironmentViewModels:SystemEnvironmentConnectionViewModel}">
                <systemEnvironment:ConnectionView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter"> <!-- this does only make it worse -->
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And the View that is used as DataTemplate:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="DependencyEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Line X1="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.X}" X2="{Binding Connection.SecondElementCoordinate.X}"
          Y1="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.Y}" Y2="{Binding Connection.SecondElementCoordinate.Y}"
          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" x:Name="ConnectionLine" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="SecondDependencyEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The Result does look nothing like I want and I know that using a `Grid` with columns probably doesn't work but it's the closest I can think of that allows to split the elements like I want.

Also the `Style` for the `ContentPresenter` seems to be wrong, because without it my Line gets drawn like I want but the `Ellipses` are wrong

Should I go for another ItemsControl just for the Ellipse?
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an Ellipse and don't put elements in Grid columns.

Instead, use Path elements with EllipseGeometries. The following example assumes that the FirstElementCoordinate and SecondElementCoordinate properties are of type `System.Windows.Point`. If that is not the case, use an appropriate Binding Converter.

```
<Canvas>
    <Line X1="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.X}"
          Y1="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate.Y}"
          X2="{Binding Connection.SecondElementCoordinate.X}"
          Y2="{Binding Connection.SecondElementCoordinate.Y}"
          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
    <Path Fill="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding Connection.FirstElementCoordinate}"
                             RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Fill="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding Connection.SecondElementCoordinate}"
                             RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There's still so much to learn about WPF for me it seems.

Comment: You're welcome. There is indeed a lot to learn, that's why there are some very good WPF books. It worth to read one or two of them. StackOverflow alone is not enough.

Comment: Could you recommend one ore more books?